# What is the maximum amount of columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, formula, multiple-columns, limit

Could you please say what is the maximum amount of columns in Google Sheets? I heard that maximum is the 256 columns but I was able to add more? Is it only limited by the sum of cells (400000)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the maximum number of cells per spreadsheet is 2000000 so if you have a one column you could have 2M rows. for column the max is 18278 which is **`ZZZ`** and can be tested with **`COLUMN`** formula:

[image: 0]

Answer (score 6):

Max number of columns in Google sheet is 18278, which means column "ZZZ" in A1 notation.

Answer (score 2):

In practice the column limit depends upon the number of rows in the same sheet and also the number of cells in other sheets in the same workbook. A workbook containing a single sheet of no more than 273 rows can extend as far as ZZZ (18,278 columns – a little under five million (4,989,894) cells for the sheet/workbook).

However, 18,278 is highly theoretical both because 273x18,278 is very awkward and the limit is much more likely to be determined either by the row count in the sheet and/or by the cell count in other sheets that are part of the same workbook.

The current upper limit of five million cells in a workbook is overriding. Hence a single sheet with 50,000 rows is limited to 100 columns (to CV). A sheet additional to one, in the same file, of 50,000 rows and 99 columns, is limited to a single column if of 50,000 rows, or five columns if of 10,000 rows, and so forth.

Columns cannot number more than 18,278 but in almost all circumstances the effective limit will be a lot less.