# GoogleSheet Column Download Limit

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Is there a limit to the number of Columns in a Spreadsheet, which could be downloaded with the googleSheetsApi(Python) ?
The response provided only gives the first 7 columns.
On trying to download individual column data beyond Column_7 , gs gives an IndexError(refer image_Response).

***SpreadSheet:***
[image]

***Response***
[image]

Comment: It seems that the current maximum number of columns in Google Spreadsheet is 18276. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56287316/7108653) And, Sheets API can retrieve those columns. But, when the number of cells is large by increasing the rows, an error occurs. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/04/25/report-handling-10000000-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) Please be careful about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot know the situation of your actual Spreadsheet from your question. So, can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can you provide your current script as a text? And, where does the error of `IndexError` occur in your script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike ,Spreadsheet has more than 7 coulmns but the response provided by GsApi does not provide columns beyond 7 .

Comment: @Tanaike ,Plz refer attached image_Spreadsheet (7+ columns) for understanding the column numbers ....and the Script & Gs Output is provided in attached imageResponse.Refer 'last 2_ for loops' in Script where Column8(row[7]) output is provided as 'IndexError' but Column7(row[6]) output is provided as spreadsheet data.

Comment: Can't share the script as it would require Auth+Api keys to work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.